# Firebase not found cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am wanted to do some bit testing with cloud function to achieve a bigger goal. As an Android developer, my knowledge is a bit limited in the case of JavaScript.

I am trying to access this database from firebase using Cloud function.

[image: Firebase Realtime Database]

My Code to access this database to get `JSON` response in Browser.

```js
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
    
    // Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into the
    // Realtime Database under the path /messages/:pushId/original
    exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      // Grab the text parameter.
      const original = req.query.text;
      // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
      admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then(snapshot => {
        // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
        res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
      });
    });
    
    // Listens for new messages added to /messages/:pushId/original and creates an
    // uppercase version of the message to /messages/:pushId/uppercase
    exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
        .onWrite(event => {
          // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
          const original = event.data.val();
          console.log('Uppercasing', event.params.pushId, original);
          const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
          // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
          // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
          // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
          return event.data.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
        });
    
    var db = admin.database();
    exports.getUserMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var query = firebase.database().ref("messages").orderByKey();
    query.once("value")
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
          var key = childSnapshot.key;
          // childData will be the actual contents of the child
          var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      });
    });  
    });
```

But I am getting the error :

> Error: could not handle the request

These are my Log error from Firebase :

```
ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    at exports.getUserMessage.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:34:49)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:47)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:635:7
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:619:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

package.json script

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7"

  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is there the issue is:

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("messages").orderByKey();
```

should be

```
db.ref("messages").orderByKey();
```

The `firebase` you're using in that line is not defined in Cloud Functions for Firebase. If you want to query the database, you already have a reference to it using the Admin SDK:

```
var db = admin.database();
```

Comment: Oops, I've now updated the code. Should've said `ref`, not `child`. If you're ever unsure what functions are available, check out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference).

Comment: By implementing your fix I was able to resolve previous error but now I am getting `Function execution took 60003 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'` error

Comment: [code](https://pastebin.com/XCNKejq1) updated but getting timeout error

Comment: @twister_void that sounds like a different problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Any suggestion on a fix as our team has to start working on cloud function and testing is not going well.

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript in general (or interacting with Firebase from JavaScript)(or the Firebase Admin SDK), Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.